# Shortcut to launch java/scala without specific classpath

Tags: java, scala

I am new to scala. Now I start to use the testing framework `scalatest`. But every time I run the test, I need to type `scala -cp /path/to/jar/folder/scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.jar my_test.scala` to include the scalatest package.

I want to type less. Here is what I think may work.

- Put `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar/folder/scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.jar;$CLASSPATH` in `.bashrc` .
- Put `alias scalat="scala -cp /path/to/jar/folder/scalatest_2.11-2.2.1.jar"` in `.bashrc` .

But I wanna know what is the common way to let scala/java know package without specific it in CLASSPATH in scala/java community?

Comment: You have to change the classpath, there is no viable alternative :) I personally prefer the second option, because I think the first one may lead to a big mess when working on several projects... <troll>But the common way is to use an IDE :P</troll>

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to use a build system like SBT or Maven (with the scala plugin) to manage your dependencies, classpath and build cycle.

Comment: To add to this. If you have an sbt project running "sbt test:console" will bring up the scala repl with the class path set properly.

Comment: I've played the sbt for a while. sbt is a brilliant build system. It looks sbt would help me build a complete environment(dependency, folders, ...) for me.  But sometimes I just want to test one simple file and don't want to involve sbt to build a project.  Like python, I can just only import unittest, write testcase, then run unittest.main() in one file.

Comment: I'm not the best person to make the case for SBT because I hate it, but  I find it worthwhile to write a maven pom even for very simple projects of two or three classes. A pom can be as simple as four or five lines of XML (you just have to define the "groupId", project name, and version) and it means your project is defined in a standard way that IDEs and other tools understand, same as any other project, and as the project grows it all just works rather than needing a messy transition. The extra directories are a chore but IDEs collapse them.